# Regex does not work as excpected

Tags: jquery, regex

see on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/yNJKj/13/

This regex is supposed to show only top level items. but it somehow sohws 2nd level items in SOME categories.

WHat am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: It's fine to link to other sites, but also include the important parts (like the regex!) *in your question itself*. StackOverflow is supposed to stand alone. Other resources can delete, get moved, etc. Also, people shouldn't have to go to another site to see your full question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the regex you want is:

```
/^.*\/activity\/[^/]*$/i
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNJKj/15/)

Or possibly

```
/^.*\/activity\/[^/]*[a-zA-Z]$/i
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNJKj/17/)

(I'm not sure why you have that single-character `[a-zA-Z]` match at the end.)

Your original

```
/^.*\/activity\/.*[a-zA-Z]$/i
```

...allows `/` to be matched by the `.*` preceding your `[a-zA-Z]`, hence including sub-categories.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it's this part, at the end of the regex:

```
\/.*[a-zA-Z]$
```

You're telling it to match the following:

1. A slash `/`
2. Anything of any length
3. An upper or lowercase letter
4. The end of the string

I'm not 100% on what you *are* and *aren't* trying to match, but that wildcard part (`.*`) is probably matching all the things you want, as well as what you don't. Making the regex more specific could help.

On an unrelated note, it would probably be more semantic and easier to work with if, instead of a single unordered list and `&nbsp;`, you reworked it to utilize nested lists. Something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="*">Category</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="*">Sub-Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="*">Sub-Category</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, if you do decide to stick with the non-breaking spaces, then couldn't you use *those* to decide what gets hidden? It looks like all you would have to do is hide anything that starts with `&nbsp;`, and that would accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change regexp to `/^.*\/activity\/[a-zA-Z]*$/i`, because `.` matchs all characters including /